# react-burger-menu isOpen prop not reacting to state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hamburger-menu

My app uses [`react-burger-menu`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu) for a mobile only hamburger menu. When an item from the menu is clicked, I'd like the menu to close, but nothing happens. (Side note - if I set `menuIsOpen: true` in the parent component, it is indeed open on page load, and the first time I click a list item the sidebar does close but if I reopen it and then try it again nothing happens.)

Parent component ([full code](https://github.com/nataliecardot/seattle-scoops/blob/master/src/components/app.js)):

```
this.state = {
  menuIsOpen: false
};

// Gets called when an item in sidebar is clicked
handleVenuesListItemClick = venue => {
    this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
};

render() {
  return (
    <Sidebar
      menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
    />
  );
```

Child component ([full code](https://github.com/nataliecardot/seattle-scoops/blob/master/src/components/sidebar.js)):

```
<Menu isOpen={this.props.menuIsOpen}>
  <div className="sidebar">

  </div>
</Menu>
```

View live version: https://nataliecardot.com/seattle-scoops/

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue. I think the problem is that you're not listening for the burger button to *open* the menu, and so the `menuIsOpen` state in the example doesn't ever get set to true. As a result, when a menu item is clicked, there is nothing to update--`menuIsOpen` is still false.

To fix, you'll need to keep your parent component's state up to date with the menu's `isOpen` state. (The library's author [has posted a few examples of this](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu/issues/218)). I am sure you can do this with hooks, but I'm inexperienced, and am not sure how. Here's an example class version, though.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

class MobileExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false
    }

  this.handleStateChange=this.handleStateChange.bind(this);
  this.handleLinkClick=this.handleLinkClick.bind(this);  
  }

  handleStateChange(state) {
    this.setState({menuOpen:state.isOpen})
  }

  handleLinkClick(e) {
    this.setState({menuOpen:false})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu onStateChange={this.handleStateChange} isOpen={this.state.menu}>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <a href="/" onClick={()=>this.handleLinkClick()}>Home</a>  
              <a href="/path-two" onClick={()=>this.handleLinkClick()}>Link text</a>
              <a href="/path-three" onClick={()=>this.handleLinkClick()}>Link text</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
```